# Broken URL in LinkedIn news feed when sharing a company update with OAuth API (PHP)

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I use the Company Share API to share updates in accordance with the LinkedIn documentation and I do post updates to LinkedIn successfully with a company ID. It works perfectly except that I get strangely broken links when updates appear in the news feed. From the company page the URLs are OK. It looks like "submitted-url" problem. Here is my PHP code:

```
$apiKey = 'xxxxxxx';
$apiSecret = 'yyyyyyyyy';
$oauth = new OAuth($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$oauth->setToken($accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);

$body = new stdClass();
$body->comment = 'Some comment';
$body->content = new stdClass();
$body->content->title = 'Some title';
$body->content->description = 'Some description';
$body->content->{'submitted-url'} = 'http://www.mycompany.com/article_id/123456';
$body->visibility = new stdClass();
$body->visibility->code = 'anyone';
$body_json = json_encode($body);

$oauth->fetch('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/12345678/shares', $body_json, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, array(
  "Content-Type" => "application/json",
  "x-li-format" => "json"
));
$response = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());
```

What I get at the LinkedIn page:

1) If you go to my company profile **http://www.linkedin.com/company/mycompany** the update links are OK (working correctly). They look like this:
**http://www.linkedin.com/company/12345678/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmycompany%2Ecom%2Fa%2Farticle_id%2123456%2F&urlhash=Srbq&actionToken=isSponsored%3Dfalse%26distanceFromViewer%3D-1%26aggregationType%3Dnone%26isPublic%3Dtrue%26verbType%3Dlinkedin%3Ashare%26activityId%3Dactivity%3A5816119308409286656%26contextId%3DeFzAC4cSPxPwhkXYLCsAAA%3D%3D%26isDigested%3Dfalse%26isFolloweeOfPoster%3Dfalse%26actorType%3Dlinkedin%3Acompany%26pageKey%3Dbiz_company_feed_mapper_first_load%26feedPosition%3D1%26actorId%3Dcompany%3A980930%26objectId%3Darticle%3A5816119686226780160%26rowPosition%3D1%26objectType%3Dlinkedin%3Aarticle%26moduleKey%3Dcompany_feed&trk=feed-article-title**

and they do redirect to the correct place on my company website from 'submitted-url' **http://www.mycompany.com/article_id/123456**

2) but if you go to the news feed at LinkedIn front page (not to my company profile): **http://www.linkedin.com/?trk=nav_logo** then the updates links do not work. They are like this:

**http://www.linkedin.com/nhome/nus-redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2Ftoday%2Fpost%2Farticle_id%2123456%2F%3Fgoback%3D%2...**

and this URL tries to redirect to some internal LinkedIn page that says "**Sorry, we couldn't find that page. Here are some others for you to explore.**". Please notice that in this case my company domain part of the update URL is missing.

Am I using a wrong code? I get no errors, and from my company profile in LinkedIn the links are working correctly.